# KIvy Camera no capture

Tags: camera, kivy, capture

I got some help trying to understand how to use a camera in an app with multiple screens. I have the capture method but I my camera shows on the screen but I get to captured picture when I press the capture button. Also, if you have any literature that simplifies the uses screen manager with inputs from different screen widgets, I would appreciate it.

main.py

```
import math
import time
import kivy
import kivy.core.text
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp, sp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

Builder.load_file('camera.kv')
Builder.load_file('inputscreen.kv')
Builder.load_file('displayscreen.kv')

class ScreenSwitch(ScreenManager):
    pass
class CameraScreen(Screen):

    def capture(self, *args):
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestamp))

class InputScreen(Screen):
    pass
class DisplayScreen(Screen):
    pass
class SettingScreen(Screen):
    pass

class tipbotApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "tipBot   " \
                     "                           version: 1"

tipbotApp().run()
```

tipbot.kv

```
ScreenSwitch:
    CameraScreen:
        name: "camera_screen"
        id: camera_screen
    InputScreen:
        name: "input_screen"
        id: input_screen
    DisplayScreen:
        name: "display_screen"
        id: display_screen
    SettingScreen:
        name: "setting_screen"
        id: setting_screen
```

camera.kv

```
<CameraScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Camera:
            id: camera
            text: "[b]CAPTURE[/b]"
            markup: True
            size_hint_y: dp(50)
            size_hint_x: dp(50)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': dp(1), 'center_y': dp(1)}

    RelativeLayout:
        Button:
            id: imgcapture
            text: "[b]CAPTURE[/b]"
            font_size: '30sp'
            markup : True
            width: self.texture_size[0] + dp(10)
            height: self.texture_size[1] + dp(10)
            size_hint: None, None
            on_press: root.capture
        Button:
            id: imagemanual
            text: "[b]MANUAL ENTRY[/b]"
            font_size: '25sp'
            markup: True
            size: dp(200), dp(50)
            pos: dp(400), dp(0)
            size_hint: None, None
            on_release: app.root.current = "input_screen"
```

Answer (score 0):

In `kv`, when you specify a method call for something like `on_press`, you must include the ending `()`. Just the opposite of almost everywhere else. Try changing:

```
on_press: root.capture
```

to:

```
on_press: root.capture()
```

Comment: I moved the method under the tipbotApp and used the app.capture(), but I still do not get a picture.